# Did Menezes et al. switch the letters $\mu$ and $\lambda$ in Floyd's cycle detection note 3.8?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, notation

The letters $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are usually used to represent, respectively, the length of the tail of the graph and length of the cycle in the graph.  But Menezes on [note 3.8](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap3.pdf), page 91 (or PDF-page 6), seems to have swapped their roles.

[image: Menezes swapping the usual roles of <span class=]$\mu$ and $\lambda$ in Floyd's cycle detection algorithm">

There's nothing wrong with the description, but isn't there a usual-role swap there?

Comment: I don't know which usage is more common, but I can't see why it matters much either way.  It's just notation, right?

Comment: Right.  It's just notation, but I think it was accidental on their part because no one in their sane mind would reverse usage like that just for fun.  Since I'm rather a beginner on the subject, I thought of throwing the ball to you guys.